# How do I achieve the expected throughput in JMeter for a given scenario?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have about 300 users (configured in the thread group) who would perform an activity (e.g.: run an e-learning course) twice. That would mean I need to expect about 600 iterations i.e 300 users performing an activity twice.

My thread group contains the following transaction controllers:

1. Login
2. Dashboard
3. Launch Course
4. Complete Course
5. Logout

As I need 600 iterations per 5400 seconds i.e 3600 + 900 + 900 seconds (1 hour steady state + 15 mins ramp-up and 15 mins ramp-down), and the sum of sampler requests within the total thread group are 18, would I be correct to say I need about 2 RPS?

Total number of iterations * number of requests per iteration = Total number of requests
600 * 18 = 10800

Total number of requests / Total test duration in seconds = Requests per second
10800 / 5400 = 2

Are my calculations correct?

In addition, what is the best approach to achieve the expected throughput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation looks more or less correct. If you need to limit your test throughput to 2 RPS you can do it using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).

---

However 2 RPS is nothing more than statistical noise, my expectation is that you need much higher load to really test your application performance, i.e.

1. Simulate the anticipated number of users for a short period. Don't care about iterations, just let your test to run i.e. for an hour with the number of users you expect. This is called [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing)
2. Do the same but for longer period of time (i.e. overnight or weekend). This is called [soak testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing).
3. Gradually increase the number of users until you will see errors or response time will start exceeding acceptable thresholds. This is called [stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dmitri. I'm acquainted with Performance and new to JMeter. The 2 RPS was an example as we will be testing multiple thread groups and also a higher number of users. I would like to know if I need to attach the Throughput Shaping Timer at the Thread Group level or Transaction level?